# How to connect Pc to Laptop as gateway to internet wuth Wlan

Tags: wireless-networking

Is it possible to use linux O/s to connect a laptop which access wireless network on internet, to desktop Machine linux O/s. I would love to make my laptop as access to internet for the desktop. 
How do I go about this without interfaces going down?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then yes, it can be done. There is some information missing but I can't comment so I will just assume you are getting your internet through an Ethernet connection to your laptop which you want to make available wirelessly.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu, you can do this quite easily. The following steps are taken from [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html).

> 1. Click the system menu Power cog icon and select System Settings.
> 2. Open Network and select Wireless on the left.
> 3. Click the Use as Hotspot... button.
> 4. If you are already connected to a wireless network, you will be asked if you want to disconnect from that network. A single wireless adapter can only connect to or create one network at a time. Click Turn On to confirm.

Now you will be able to connect from your desktop computer to the wireless hotspot created by your laptop.